# Any simple way to get svn status update in chronological

Tags: svn

I use:

svn status --show-updates --verbose |less

but results are not sorted in chronological order. What do you use to do this ?
thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Linux (or other UNIX-like systems) you can do something like

```
svn status --show-updates --verbose | sort -k 2rn
```

to sort by the middle column of revision numbers (in reverse). I guess that might work from Cygnus too but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 4):

This pipeline gets the file paths from the svn status output and uses normal ls to sort them by (local) modified time.

```
svn status | awk '{print $2}' | xargs ls -lt
```

Answer (score 2):

```
svn log --limit 10
```

SVN log lists in reverse-chronological order by default.

Comment: +1 thank you, that's indeed another way to do it, adding the --verbose to get the file names